# Why do I suddenly get ERR_TIMED_OUT when trying to access gitlab only from my Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

Accessing gitlab was fine then all of a sudden when I try to access it it keeps throwing ERR_TIMED_OUT.Here are the things that I tried but didn't work:

- I tried changing the DNS to 2 other different DNS servers than the default one, but it didn't work.
- I tried removing all docker containers that are running to eliminate the possibility of having a container interrupting with the network settings.
- I tried disabling the IPv6 , I am not sure if I did it right though by editing /etc/resolve.conf
- I tried pinging gitlab.com from the terminal and it worked fine, then pinged google.com for comparison and I think google pinging worked better, but I don't know what does that indicate? you can find the ping screenshot below
  [image: ping gitlab and google]

- I tried accessing gitlab using the same device but using a mobile hotspot and it worked fine, I also tried accessing gitlab from the same wifi I am using but through a mobile device and it worked fine, I don't know what does that signify.
- I also tried using vpn to access gitlab and it worked.
- I tried Google Chrome and Firefox, had the same results.

I can't figure out what's the problem, is there anything that I might do to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its common problem in egypt i think its blocked by our ISP

Comment: It got solved when I used a vpn, so it seems like that's actually true.